# ServiceStack Validation Feature Throws Exception

Tags: servicestack

I am trying to implement validation feature in ServiceStack to validate my RequestDTO's before calling db operations.
When i try to validate request dto like

```
ValidationResult result = this.AddBookingLimitValidator.Validate(request);
```

the code automatically throws a validation error automatically.
I can not even debug service what is happening behind the scenes ? Can i change that behaviour or am i doing something wrong here.
Thanks.

My Request DTO :

```
[Route("/bookinglimit", "POST")]
[Authenticate]
public class AddBookingLimit : IReturn<AddBookingLimitResponse>
{       
  public int ShiftId { get; set; }
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }
  public int Limit { get; set; }
}
```

My Response DTO :

```
public class AddBookingLimitResponse
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Validation class :

```
public class AddBookingLimitValidator : AbstractValidator<AddBookingLimit>
{
  public AddBookingLimitValidator()
  {
    RuleFor(r => r.Limit).GreaterThan(0).WithMessage("Limit 0 dan büyük olmalıdır");
  }
}
```

Service Implementation :

```
public AddBookingLimitResponse Post(AddBookingLimit request)
{
  ValidationResult result = this.AddBookingLimitValidator.Validate(request);          

  Shift shift = new ShiftRepository().Get(request.ShiftId);
  BookingLimit bookingLimit = new BookingLimit
  {
    RestaurantId = base.UserSession.RestaurantId,
    ShiftId = request.ShiftId,
    StartDate = request.Date.AddHours(shift.StartHour.Hour).AddMinutes(shift.StartHour.Minute),
    EndDate = request.Date.AddHours(shift.EndHour.Hour).AddMinutes(shift.EndHour.Minute),
    Limit = request.Limit,
    CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
    CreatedBy = base.UserSession.UserId,
    Status = (byte)Status.Active
  };
  return new AddBookingLimitResponse
  {
    Id = new BookingLimitRepository().Add(bookingLimit)
  };
        }
```

AppHost code :

```
container.RegisterValidators(typeof(AddBookingLimitValidator).Assembly);
Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());
```

And i consume the service in c# code:

```
 try
 {
   AddBookingLimitResponse response = ClientHelper.JsonClient.Post(new AddBookingLimit
   {
     Date = DateTime.Parse(DailyBookingLimitDateTextBox.Text),
     Limit = Convert.ToInt32(DailyBookingLimitTextBox.Text),
     ShiftId = Convert.ToInt32(DailyDayTypeSelection.SelectedValue)
    });
    WebManager.ShowMessage(UserMessages.SaveSuccessful.FormatString(Fields.BookingLimit));
  }
  catch (WebServiceException ex)
  {
    WebManager.ShowMessage(ex.ResponseStatus.Message);           
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, ServiceStack validates the request DTO before the service gets called if the `ValidationFeature` is enabled.

To manually invoke the validator in the service, you have to remove this line from your `AppHost` first:

```
Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());
```

Please make sure that the validator property in your service has the type `IValidator<>`, otherwise it won't be injected by the IoC container if you register your validators with `container.RegisterValidators(typeof(AddBookingLimitValidator).Assembly)`.

```
public class TestService : Service
{
    public IValidator<Request> Validator { get; set; }

    public RequestResponse Post(Request request)
    {
        Validator.Validate(request); 
        ...
    }
}
```